# AWS XRay PutTraceSegments

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-xray

I'm trying to execute a command `aws xray put-trace-segments --trace-segment-documents "$DOC" --endpoint-url "http://0.0.0.0:2000/" --debug true` but I'm receiving an error `Invalid Entity`. I'm using the example of this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-api-sendingdata.html#xray-api-segments

```json
{
    "UnprocessedTraceSegments": [
        {
            "ErrorCode": "ParseError",
            "Message": "Invalid entity. ErrorCode: ParseError"
        },
        {
            "ErrorCode": "ParseError",
            "Message": "Invalid entity. ErrorCode: ParseError"
        }
    ]
}
```

The put-trace-segment keeps giving me an error. Am I missing something else here?

Comment: Can you make sure you are following the segment document requirements as mentioned in this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-api-segmentdocuments.html

Comment: I did also follow that one. But it's not working on my side. Maybe the doc I've observed is a bit outdated (or maybe there's something wrong with how I did but I just follow the steps in there).